# coffeescript with jquery ajax

Tags: coffeescript

```
$.ajax '/',
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'html' error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        $('body').append "AJAX Error: #{textStatus}"
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        $('body').append "Successful AJAX call: #{data}"
```

there is something wrong with the above code,I can't compile it into js

Comment: -_-|||,i found the reason , it mixed with "tab" and "space" ,so it can't work

Comment: no,i use the coffeescript.js in the webpage ,not the command line,so nothing appeared , and how to debug the coffeescript ?

Comment: When using `coffee-script.js`, you should see compile-time errors on your browser's console. If your browser doesn't have a console, grab the [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) bookmarklet.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The compiler gives the error

```
Parse error on line 3: Unexpected 'IDENTIFIER'
```

referring to the line

```
dataType: 'html' error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
```

The problem is simply that there's no comma (or line break) between `'html'` and `error`. Here's the fixed code:

```
$.ajax '/',
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'html'
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        $('body').append "AJAX Error: #{textStatus}"
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        $('body').append "Successful AJAX call: #{data}"
```

I highly recommend using an editor with a built-in "Build" command, especially one that can work on selected text. It makes syntax errors a lot easier to pin down.

Comment: NetBeans is one such editor that so far I like for a free IDE. Look under tools->plugins to add the CoffeeScript plugin then right click your .coffee file and select CoffeeScript->autocompile. No need to install commandline tools.

Comment: @trevor do you recommend a particular build system for the editor?  Ideally Sublime Text?  Currently I am using a build system as part of a framework.

Comment: @Scoop If you're using the official [CoffeeScript tmbundle](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle) with ST2, there should already be a Build command that works for your CoffeeScript.